# Android Mediaplayer Streaming - Worked now it doesn't

Tags: java, android

I have a strange problem.  I have an mp3 stream I am trying to utilize within an application (2.1).  Before you say streaming isn't supported here, it seems to be.

I was able to get it working last night by using the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Stream extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource("http://ipaddress:8000/");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
  }
}
```

However, today, it doesn't work.  Furthermore, last night -- I was able to use the Internet Browser on my android phone to stream it.  Although, last night when I went to the address, it opened the stream in video player.  Nonetheless, I am unable to open it today in the browser, either.

In the browser, I keep getting the "page not displayed" page.  I have actually verified it is online.  I can browse to it from my PC (on the same network), and have confirmed internet connectivity to my android by utilizing other streaming applications and browsing to other web pages.

I am stumped as to why my code (or the stream) suddenly stopped working overnight on the phone.  The code even works on a 2.1 emulator (and streams it).

Let me know what you all think, please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a connectivity problem on the network side.  Too many connections were opened from the phone on WiFi to the streaming server.  This caused an IP blacklist.  Today, this seems to have cleared up.